# Element-wise matrix vector multiplication and division without assignment in RcppArmadillo

Tags: r, rcpp, armadillo

I have a slow R function I am converting to RcppArmadillo. I am very new to Rcpp and RcppArmadillo. I managed to code up something that works, but it seems clunky and not as fast at it probably could be. Mainly, I am curious how to perform matrix-vector element-wise multiplication or division of an output without needing to assign it to a new object first. For example here is my RcppArmadillo function which works:

```
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]

using namespace Rcpp;
using namespace arma;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
arma::mat TTD(arma::mat X, arma::vec d, arma::vec taubar){
    arma::vec top = d % sqrt(taubar);
    arma::mat cubed = pow(X,3) * 4 * datum::pi;
    arma::mat out = repmat(top,1,X.n_cols)/sqrt(cubed.each_col() % d); 
  return out;
}
```

But, can I do something like (and I know this is wrong): `pow(X,3).n_cols() % d  * 4 * datum::pi`? And also how can I divide the vector `top` by the matrix without using `repmat` or assigning the product of `d % sqrt(taubar)` to the new object first? I don't want to change any of my inputs in place because I need them later in R for other functions.

Below is the R code which tests the function:

```
library(RcppArmadillo)
library(Rcpp)

sourceCpp("TTD.cpp")

d <- c(53.638145,  9.617256,  1.450767)

ttau <- matrix(c(36.405117983,  1.707159588,  0.000010000, 36.406568363,  1.707759972,  0.001141475,
           36.408022369,  1.708361856, 0.002275780, 36.409480010,  1.708965246,  0.003412920),
           nrow = 3, ncol = 4)

tau_bar <- c(66.48201,  9.90116,  6.08173)


TTD(X = ttau, d = d,taubar = tau_bar)
```

My actual matrices and vectors will be much larger, thus the need for the speed increase.

Comment: You're not doing any matrix operation here, right? So, why using {RcppArmadillo} instead of a loop?

Comment: You mean as opposed to a loop over vectors as rows or columns of the matrix X? I am working with an input matrix and multiplying/dividing it by vectors, but that is not matrix operation?

Comment: I call matrix operations things like matrix-matrix multiplication. Here, it seems that you could do what you want to do in one pass of your matrix with two nested loops.

Comment: Okay, I got this going in Rcpp with looping over columns. It's faster but could be improved. Maybe I will delete this question and post a new one.

Comment: I think you can't do better than one pass over your matrix in Rcpp (column-wise).